# Difference between double declining balance and reducing balance

Tags: financial-literacy, accounting, assets, depreciation

As I understand it if we have a double declining balance asset worth £10,000, declining over 10 years, we will depreciate by an annual rate of 20%.

But I have also been told that double declining is not identical to reducing balance.

So, I ask, what is the difference?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Reducing balance is otherwise known as declining balance. Double declining is what it sounds: Doubling the rate of the declining balance of the asset.

> To calculate depreciation under the double declining method, multiply
>   the book value at the beginning of the fiscal year by a multiple of
>   the straight-line rate of depreciation. The double declining balance
>   formula is:
>
> Double-declining balance (ceases when the book value = the estimated
>   salvage value)
>
> 2  ×  Straight-line depreciation rate  ×  Book value at the beginning
>   of the year

http://www.accountingtools.com/double-declining-balance-depre

Reducing balance on the other hand:

> Definition: Reducing Balance Depreciation is calculated by charging a
>   higher rate in the early part of the assets life. This method is
>   considered for any asset that has a high usage in the early part of
>   their life. An example of how this is calculated is show below. The
>   amount of depreciation reduces as the life of the asset progresses.
>
> Example An asset has a useful life of 3 years Cost of the asset was
>   £4,000 Residual or Scrap Value is £300 Rate of depreciation is 50%
>   Depreciation to be expensed for the three years will be:
>          NBV     R.V     Rate    Depreciation Accumalated Depreciation
>
> Year1: (4,000 - 300) x 50% = 1,850 1,850
>
> Year2: (2,150 - 300) x 50% = 925 2,775
>
> Year3: (1,225 - 300) x 50% = 925* 3,700

https://debitoor.com/dictionary/reducing-balance-depreciation